# h2o Distributed Random Forest maximum features parameter

Tags: python, random-forest, h2o, hyperparameters

I am hyperparameter tuning a random forest and I would like to tune the parameter regarding the maximum features of each tree. By sklearn's [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) it is:

> The number of features to consider when looking for the best split: If
>   int, then consider max_features features at each split.
>
> - If float, then max_features is a percentage and int(max_features * n_features) features are considered at each split.
> - If “auto”, then max_features=sqrt(n_features).
> - If “sqrt”, then max_features=sqrt(n_features) (same as “auto”).
> - If “log2”, then max_features=log2(n_features).
> - If None, then max_features=n_features.

I tried looking through the h2o [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/drf.html) to no avail.

Does this parameter or any of the different ways you can adjust that parameter (e.g. log of features) exist in h2o?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name for this parameter in H2O Random Forest is [mtries](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/mtries.html).